# Почему на 1 процесс макс. 1 консоль?

Tags: windows, консоль, история

Мне просто интересно, почему на 1 процесс приходится 1 консоль? Ведь у обычных ("графических") окон такого ограничения нет. Почему нельзя было просто сделать 2 типа окон: с CUI и с GUI? Какая была история у этого решения?

Пока всё выглядит так, как будто раньше никому не нужно было много консолей на 1 процесс, и тут решили оптимизировать, даровав процессу только 1-у консоль. Возможно, это было связанно с дизайном консольного приложения, мол, зачем консольному приложению 2 консоли? — делайте всё в 1-й!

Comment: может потому, что "один монитор, одна клавиатура, одна консоль" ? просто посмотрите на старые майнфреймы.

Answer (score 0):

Консоль в Windows пришла из [DOS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS). Раньше, до [защищенного режима](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%89%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC), компьютеры умели выполнять одновременно только один процесс на весь компьютер.

> DOS является однозадачной операционной системой[6]. После запуска управление передаётся прикладной программе, которая получает в своё распоряжение все ресурсы компьютера и может осуществлять ввод-вывод посредством как функций, предоставляемых операционной системой, так и функций базовой системы ввода-вывода (BIOS), а также работать с устройствами напрямую.

То есть, изначально консоль существовала для старых legacy-приложений, которые написаны для DOS, и, соответственно, не умели работать с окнами.

Comment: консоль пришла в дос, а не "из". Консоль существовала много много лет.

Comment: Я имел в виду консоль в Windows пришла из DOS

Comment: даже если она пришла с доса, Ваш ответ не есть ответом на вопрос. Никто (теоретически) не мешал иметь два монитора и две клавиатуры для работы с одним процессом.

Comment: Какие два монитора? когда у тебя 512кб оперативной памяти и загрузка системы  с магнитной ленты? какие два монитора?

Comment: т.е. в DOS были функции для работы только с 1-й консолью? но почему тогда просто не сделать новые функции для работы с несколькими консолями, а если вызвать `AllocConsole` 2 раза без соответствующего вызова `FreeConsole` после 1-го, то просто выдавать ошибку; а также пометить их (`AllocConsole`, `FreeConsole` и проч. функции, которые не принимают внутрь себя handle stdout/-in/-err) как не рекомендуемые для использования?

Comment: @DiD - 512 кб памяти - это очень круто было. для отрисовки текстового экрана нужно всего то 25*80 - около 2килобайт памяти. То есть, абсолютно ничего (кроме большой стоимости манитора и железа) не мешало иметь два монитора, которые были бы как две консоли. Ну и ещё добавить возможность переключать выбранный монитор. Но потом появился screen и все стало ок:)

Comment: До появления IBM PC/AT, DOS разрабатывался для работы без мониторов. А терминалы, такие как VT100 были совместимы только с Unix-семейством ОС. Не для отрисовки, а для хранения 80х25 нужно 2кб, это если изображение имеет один цвет текста и один цвет фона, а если 16 цветов текста и 16 цветов фона, это уже 16кб. И это только для хранения видео-режима цифро-аналогового преобразователя.

Comment: @KoVadim Да и какая разница сколько мониторов подключенно к компьютеру. Суть MSDOS такова, что он выполняет только одну программу, эта программа может запустить другую программу, но пока другая программа не выполнится, эта программа не может выполняться. Как бы работает как функции в языке СИ, и даже ключевое слово return так называется, потому что имело назначение не передать результат работы функции, а возвратить контроль управления.

Comment: никто не спорит с тем, что программа одна. Но выводить она вполне могла бы на два экрана. достаточно одной функции для того, что бы выбрать активный терминал/консоль

Comment: @KoVadim, а зачем? на тот момент такой надобности не было. Я не уверен даже в том, есть ли в них необходимость и в 2020. А на тот момент тем более, эти все терминалы были для гиков, никто не ставил чьи-то удобства важнее основных целей. ЭВМ - она не должна быть удобной, она должна считать, вычислять, с чем прекрасно справлялась и без монитора совсем. Чуть позже компьютеры стали использовать для контроля каких-то процессов, мониторинга... Спустя время, цифровое отображение разных показателей полностью сменило аналоговые приборы со стрелками. Но я не понимаю. Приведите примеры, зачем это сейчас?

Comment: Вы попутали меня с автором вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Исторически, приложения текстового режима обмениваются данными между собой и пользователем через механизм стандартных потоков ввода-вывода. STDOUT и STDERR программы верхнего уровня выводится в консоль, когда она запускает какую-то дочернюю программу то может пробрасывать ее STDOUT и STDERR или потребляет STDOUT и пробрасывает STDERR, так что вывод дочерней программы может попадать пользователю, и т.д. Как видно, такая схема создана с расчётом на то, что 1 консоль будет не просто на 1 процесс, а на целое дерево процессов.

При этом никто не мешает сделать некоторую утилиту, которая будет не будет работать со стандартными потоками ввода-вывода по этой схеме, а, например, будет делать консоли по требованию с вводом-выводом в них из предоставленного дескриптора, или разделять одно консольное окно между разными приложениями.